# How to drop pandas rows that has partial match of substring?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe , I want to drop rows that has partial substring match as below, and save those to new csv file . The below line of code works fine , but I did not know how to drop those rows from the original dataframe (`df2`) and save the output to other csv file .

```
df2_output=df2[df2['Name'].str.contains("planning|Test|tgt",case=False)]
```

Appreciate your support
Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want select non matched values by inverting mask by `~`:

```
df3_output=df2[~df2['Name'].str.contains("planning|Test|tgt",case=False)]
```

Or for improve performance (test only once, not 2 times) save output of mask to variable:

```
mask = df2['Name'].str.contains("planning|Test|tgt",case=False)
df2_output=df2[mask]
df3_output=df2[~mask] 

df2_output.to_csv('matched.csv', index=False)
df3_output.to_csv('non_matched.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you, i did this , it works but i was hoping to drop from the original dataframe to not produce many files ..but it works this way too